# Python: Efficient way to move a huge list of data from one list to another

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing, move

I'm using `multiprocessing`, and in a separate process (let's call it thread for clarity), I'm using PySerial to pull data from a device. In my program, I have a list that's shared with the main thread. I create the list using:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
#... stuff
self.mpManager = mp.Manager()
self.shared_return_list = self.mpManager.list()
```

This list, is filled inside the process, and then this is transferred to the local thread using:

```
if len(self.acqBuffer) < 50000:
    try:
        self.shared_result_lock.acquire()
        self.acqBuffer.extend(self.shared_return_list)
        del self.shared_return_list[:]
    finally:
        self.shared_result_lock.release()
```

where `acqBuffer` is the local list that takes the data for analysis and storage.

The problem is that if the device has lots of data queued, the transfer process will become really, really slow as lots of data is there, and the GUI freezes. Possible solutions are either to transfer the data in chunks and actively keep reviving the GUI, or find a smart way to transfer the data, which is what I'm asking about.

In C++, I would use some derivative of `std::deque` or `std::list` (which is not necessarily contiguous in memory) with a move constructor and use `std::move` to just push the pointer to the data, instead of re-copying the whole data to the main thread. Is such a thing possible in my case in Python? Are there smarter ways to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the data stored in the list all the same type or not?

Comment: @shuttle87 It's all strings, but with different lengths. So like `["Hi","There","What are you","doing"]`.

Comment: @JaredGoguen Actually this is not valid for my program, because this will assign a new non-shared list. The only valid type I could use is `mpManager.list()`, and I'd avoid recreating such a complicated, shared structure repeatedly, especially that this list is passed as a parameter to the function that is called through `mp.Process()`.

Comment: I don't understand. `shared_return_list` is stored in its own process. The only way to move it to another process it by copying it. If you don't want a copy, it needs to be stored in the same process, and if you need it shared that means it needs to be in shared memory.

Comment: It's a bit difficult that the underlying data is strings of variable length. The shared memory library I was involved in writing was inspired by almost this exact same use case, but with fixed width data: https://github.com/JaggedVerge/mmap_backed_array There might be a way of using something like that to do what you want. Alternatively if you don't mind introducing complexity you could use some sort of message queue or key-value store to do what you need.

Comment: @Veedrac No, buddy. `shared_return_list` is not stored in its own process. I've shown that it's a *shared* list instantiated from `multiprocessing.Manager()`. It's shared between the main process and the sub-process.

Comment: @shuttle87 Thank you for the suggestion. I'll keep it in mind. Maybe I can combine it with some other idea and create a solution.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist "A manager object returned by `Manager()` controls a server process which holds Python objects and allows other processes to manipulate them using proxies." - https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @Veedrac I'm sorry, I don't understand your point. Thinking about this as pointers and memory elements, I don't see any difference.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist The values are literally stored in the memory of another process. The other processes *can't* just access these, since they exist in another virtual address space.